# How to upgrade expo/vector-icons?

Tags: react-native, version-control, expo, version, upgrade

I upgraded expo/vector-icons from version 12 to 13. In web it works fine but in expo react-native i have the following error:

```
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo package version:
 - @expo/vector-icons - expected version: ^12.0.0 - actual version installed: 13.0.0
 - expo-updates - expected version: ~0.11.7 - actual version installed: 0.11.6
```

I have tried deleting yarn.lock and node_modules and reinstalling. Why does the project expect version 12? how can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

```
expo install react-native-svg@12.1.1

expo install react-native-safe-area-context@3.3.2
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck